# How to connect 3 monitors to my new laptop

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have a M4800 and have 3 monitors running windows7. I have connected 1 monitor to the VGA port, 1 monitor connected via usb video adapter and i have  1 monitor connected to display port.
the one on the display port is not getting extended display.
do i need another video card or Do i have a misconfiguration?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may depend on the configuration you have. I think there are several options on that model. But from my quick look, it appears as though 3 external monitors is no problem, at least to the version that has the high res internal screen.

See [here](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3519/t/19542883) as a reference.